# JWPlayer, disallow script access

Tags: html, jwplayer, flash

Is there a way to configure jwplayer to disable script access?

I've tried this but it's not disabling script access

```
jwplayer("divID").setup({
  flashplayer: "theswf.swf",
  allowscriptaccess: "never",
  playlist: [
     { file: "../file.mp4", duration: 10 }
  .... etc
```

I've also tried by getting the object and setting params, but it's not setting the param, i.e.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0];
x.addParams("allowscriptaccess", "never");
```

But addParams is giving an uncaught type, undefined is not a function.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: You would need to set this in jwplayer.js, I believe.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer I'm pretty sure you're right.. I'm going to try it out now, if you want to add an answer I'll accept if it works